# How to debug hibernate-wakeup problem in 17.10?

Tags: hibernate, wakeup

In 17.04, hibernate worked good. Now since 17.10 the PC does not come up after hibernation. Something starts, but the screens stays black and the keyboard lights do not go on. /var/log/syslog is empty for that time, nothing is logged. Suspend works.
How can I further debug this to find out what it could be?

(PC with Asus mainboard and Intel i7 CPU, Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.13.0-37)

Answer (score 1):

After installing kernel 4.16.0-041600rc5-generic it worked.

I went to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
and changed into the directory v4.16-rc5/.
From there I downloaded

```
linux-headers-4.16.0-041600rc5_4.16.0-041600rc5.201803112130_all.deb
linux-headers-4.16.0-041600rc5-generic_4.16.0-041600rc5.201803112130_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.16.0-041600rc5-generic_4.16.0-041600rc5.201803112130_amd64.deb
```

and did

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*
```

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Last two steps would be `rm linux-*` and `reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

All of this works well for me for hibernating to file, thanks for the instructions! In my case I also had to get the latest stable kernel for hibernate to file to work, i.e. Ubuntu 17.10 and a dell xps 9370, I had to upgrade the kernel to 4.16.0rc

Note that if hibernating to file, you still have to do the whole filefrag stuff to copy the physical_offset to the etc/default/grub file,e.g. GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=swap_file_deb_partition resume_offset=physical_offset_as_filefrag_says" and then do not forget to run sudo update-grup and reboot for changes to take effect!